# How to transform current Date in a specific Number in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have the following Oracle SQL Statement in my SQL Select clause, which transform a date like `01.04.2015` into `78`, `01.07.2015` into `79` and so on (the value of beginDate could be `01.04.2015` or `01.07.2015`):

```
SELECT to_char(beginDate, 'q') + 4 * to_char(beginDate, 'yy') + 16
FROM myDateValuesTable;
```

Now it is important for me to transform always the current Date into the same values in Java by using the same kind of math expression. I have no idea, how I can programming these steps in Java? Here is a first idea:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);   // the value is 2015
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); // the value is 09
int quarter = (month / 3) + 1;            // the value is 3
```

For the `01.04.2015` it must be transformed into `78` and for the `01.07.2015` into `79`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am not able to understand how it computes `78 for "01.04.2015"`. Can you explain?

Comment: Where is `quartal` defined in `SELECT to_char(beginDate, 'q') + 4 * to_char(beginDate, 'yy') + 16 quartal`?

Comment: quartal was an alias to set a sepcific column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
System.out.println(month / 3 + 1 + 4 * (year % 100) + 16);
```

Oracle `'q'` returns the quarter of the year. This is obtained in Java by getting the month value and calculating `month / 3 + 1`.

Then, Oracle `'yy'` returns the last two digits of the year. This is obtained in Java by getting the year value and calculating `year % 100`.

You can test it with the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getNumber("01.04.2015")); // prints 78
    System.out.println(getNumber("01.07.2015")); // prints 79
}

private static int getNumber(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(dateStr);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    return month / 3 + 1 + 4 * (year % 100) + 16;
}
```